# Spliting a string on the basis of regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text file

```
"Zanesville,OH"        +39.93830        -82.00830      84ZC  PMNQ
"Zaragoza,Spain"        +41.66670         -1.05000      GWC7  PXB0
"Zurich,Switzerland"        +47.36670         +8.53330      HP9Z  QVT0
"Zwickau,Germany"        +50.70000        +12.50000      J17H  RFH0
```

Now i want the values in each line. there are many spaces between values. i know that regex can be used to get the values. but i am unable to make one. the code that i am using to read file is this

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\files\\cities.txt");  
          if (file.exists()) {
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
              String line = "";
              while ((line = br.readLine())!= null) {
                  String token[] =line.split(" ");

              }
          }
```

Can anyone tell me how can i get the values??

Comment: What's your expected output from doing whatever you wanted to do after processing the data from the text file?

Comment: What do you mean by values?

Comment: i want to make a csv file from the above file

Comment: @AvinashRaj city names and the information in front of it

Comment: If you want to get individual words in each line, why don't you split each line?

Comment: You can use regex to split on "one or more" whitespaces. `String token[] = line.split("\\s+");`

Comment: `file.exists()` isn't the right check to use. Use `file.isFile()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split the input according to the below regex,

```
\\s+(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)
```

Code:

```
String s = "\"Zanesville,OH\"        +39.93830        -82.00830      84ZC  PMNQ\n" + 
        "\"Zaragoza,Spain\"        +41.66670         -1.05000      GWC7  PXB0\n" + 
        "\"Zurich,Switzerland\"        +47.36670         +8.53330      HP9Z  QVT0\n" + 
        "\"Zwickau,Germany, United States\"        +50.70000        +12.50000      J17H  RFH0";
String[] tok = s.split("\\s+(?=(?:[^\"]*+\"[^\"]*+\")*+[^\"]*+$)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tok));
```

Output:

```
["Zanesville,OH", +39.93830, -82.00830, 84ZC, PMNQ
"Zaragoza,Spain", +41.66670, -1.05000, GWC7, PXB0
"Zurich,Switzerland", +47.36670, +8.53330, HP9Z, QVT0
"Zwickau,Germany, United States", +50.70000, +12.50000, J17H, RFH0]
```

Comment: Breaks though if anything but the first value is enclosed in ""

Comment: i don't know what do you mean. Could you provide an ex?

Comment: This will not match `\"Zanesville,OH\"        +39.93830        \"-82.00830\"      84ZC  PMNQ`

Comment: Yes you can even make it faster with possessive quantifiers: `"\\s+(?=[^\"]*+(?:\"[^\"]*+\"[^\"]*+)*+$)"`

Comment: You have to do this, or Java will break down on worst case heavy backtracking expressions

Comment: Quick Benchmark: Your original: 1152ms, possessive: 767ms -- (100k Runs, 700k for warmup, then median of 3 100k rounds)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `line.split("\\s+(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")` regex pattern to make your desired output.

Comment: That'll work for the sample input, but will cause trouble if there are spaces in the city names.  "New York,NY", for instance, will break it.

Comment: @BlairHippo to fix that you could use `(?<=[\"A-Z\\d])\\s+`

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are trying to do, but it doesn't work... Breaks for "Zanes ville. O H "

Answer (score 1):

***A more generic solution for Excel like CSV***

This looks like to have been originally **tab-separated text**, tabs replaced by multiple spaces. The double quotes suggests **CSV** like from Excel.

As text between double quotes may contain a line break (multiline text), I start of with the entire text.

```
String encoding =  "Windows-1252"; // English, best would be "UTF-8".
byte[] textAsBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
String text = new String(textAsBytes, encoding);
```

Excel uses for (Windows) line endings `"\r\n"`. And in multi-line text `"\n"`.

```
String[] lines = text.split("\r\n");
```

Splitting on multiple spaces `.split("  +")` might break inside a quoted field. So I use a pattern.
This pattern uses either something quoted, where any internal quote is self-escaped as two quotes. Or a sequence of non-whitespace.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"^([^\"]|\"\")*\"|\\S+");
for (String line: lines) {
     List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
     Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
     while (m.find()) {
         String field = m.group();
         if (fields.startsWith("\"") && field.endsWith("\"") && field.length() >= 2) {
             field = field.substring(1, field.length() - 1); // Strip quotes.
             field = field.replace("\"\"", "\""); // Unescape inner quotes.
         }
         fields.add(field));
     }
     ...
}
```